# How can i save data for each loop in batch

Tags: batch-file, save

What i am trying to do is save data for each time i loop, and eventually i want to figure out how to use a for loop to save all of the data for each iteration of the loop. What i have so far is this.

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set X=1
set Y=1
set SUMVALUE=1
set LOOPVALUE=0
set XMAXVAL=3
set YMAXVAL=3
set /a SUMVALUE=%XMAXVAL% * %YMAXVAL%

:LOOP
cls
set /a LOOPVALUE=%LOOPVALUE% + 1
>Data.sav echo %X%,%Y%
set /a Y=%Y% + 1
if %Y% gtr %YMAXVAL% ( set /a X=%X% + 1 
set Y=1)
if %LOOPVALUE% geq %SUMVALUE% goto END 
goto LOOP 

:END
cls
pause
```

And I know this doesn't make sense because what its doing is its going through the loop each time and rewriting what the %X%,%Y% is so then it will end with 3,3 but I have no idea how i can change it so that it will break and create a new save line so then it would be 1,1(break)2,1 etc. if anyone knows how to do this it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you not just send an output of the variable values to a file? For example, echo %X% > file.txt will send the value of "X" to a text file, and then replacing with >> the next time round will append the next value to the file (">" is used to create a file if it doesn't exist or overwrite if it does, which you don't want to use every time if you are iterating and adding more data).

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but I think this is what you want: replace `>Data.sav echo %X%,%Y%` by `>>Data.sav echo %X%,%Y%` and put `>Data.sav break` somewhere before `:LOOP`, so you append the new `X`/`Y` pair to the file `Data.sav` rather tha replacing it; the new line creates an empty file and overwrites an already existing one, so you get new data every time you run the batch file...

Comment: Thanks. Using >> instead does exactly what I want tit to do. Thanks for the help guys.